# Makefile separate directories

Tags: makefile

It really takes a long time to read the make and gcc manual. Since I just need some basic function of them, I want to learn them quickly.

The project directory is like the following.

```
CWD
|----Source----1.cpp
|----Header----1.h
|----Object----1.o
|----Makefile
```

There are three directories and one Makefile in Current Working Directories, and "1.cpp" includes "1.h". I want to use Makefile which is in the CWD to compile the project such that the object output is in Object directory.

This is simplified version of the problem I have now. Since it is relatively hard to begin from scratch, could anyone help me to write a Makefile for this simple problem? And I will try to learn from it and solve my own problem. Or could anyone suggests which parts of make and gcc I need to learn to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This will be enough to compile the source and produce the object:

```
Object/1.o: Source/1.cpp Header/1.h
    $(CXX) -c Source/1.cpp -IHeader -o Object/1.o
```

If you want to build an executable, maybe called "one", add another rule above that:

```
one: Object/1.o
    $(CXX) Object/1.o -o one

Object/1.o: Source/1.cpp Header/1.h
    $(CXX) -c Source/1.cpp -IHeader -o Object/1.o
```

To clean things up a little, use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
one: Object/1.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

Object/1.o: Source/1.cpp Header/1.h
    $(CXX) -c $< -IHeader -o $@
```

And if you want to make the second rule more general, so that it can handle more objects you can turn the second rule into a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) and separate the header dependency of `1.o`:

```
one: Object/1.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

Object/1.o: Header/1.h

Object/%.o: Source/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< -IHeader -o $@
```

And of course there is a lot more you can do, when you're ready.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to compile all the things now. And I begin to read the manual...